# Is it safe to clear buffer/cache while program is running in linux os?

Tags: linux

Hi program named methratio.py needed to clear the buffer/cache so I need use
sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
I am wondering if it is okay to use while other program such as downloading some stuff, copying the files.

Based on what I searched, I think it will be fine.
But I'm not sure, and I don't wanna take a risk cuz I don't want to ruin others project.
Thank you. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Pages have a reference count to indicate their usage. Only unused pages are released.

Answer (score 0):

Is it safe? Yes, it should be safe to do this when doing testing and debugging. It should not cause filesystem consistency issues.

> This is a non-destructive operation and will not free any dirty objects.

But on heavily loaded production system, you may see performance degradations because lots of cached objects will need to be reloaded.

> Use of this file can cause performance problems.  Since it discards cached
> objects, it may cost a significant amount of I/O and CPU to recreate the
> dropped objects, especially if they were under heavy use.  Because of this,
> use outside of a testing or debugging environment is not recommended.

Whether or not it is safe to do this in production systems depends on whether you have any workload running on the system that is sensitive to this performance degradation.